# program organizing a table by swaping max and mins with the edges (keeps doing it until done)

Tags: c, codeblocks

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    void minimaxi(int t[],int bs,int bi,int *ma,int *mi){
    int j;
    *ma=bi; *mi=bi;
    for(j=bi;j<=bs;j++){
    if (t[j]<t[*mi]) { *mi=j;} ;
     } 
    for(j=bi;j<=bs;j++){
    if (t[j]>t[*ma]) { *ma=j;} ;
    }

      }
    void permut(int *x, int *y){
    *x=*x+*y;
    *y=*x-*y;
    *x=*x-*y; 
     }
   void triminmax(int t[], int n){
   int bi, bs, mx, mn;
   bs=n-1;
   bi=0;
   do {
  minimaxi(t,bs,bi,&mx,&mn);
   permut(&t[mx],&t[bs]);
  permut(&t[mn],&t[bi]);
   
   bs=bs-1;
   bi++;
   }     while(bs>=bi);
     }



    int main()
    {
      int t[100], bs, bi, n, i,z;
     printf("give the table length \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    z=n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     printf("enter T[%d]\n", i);
    scanf("%d", t+i);
     }
     triminmax(t,n);
     for(i=0;i<z;i++){
    printf("%d\n", t[i]);
    }

    return 0;
     }
```

The aim is to create a program that organizes a table using the following:
starts by finding the max and the min between case 0 and case n-1 (last case)
then swaps the max with the case n-1 and the min with case 0
then it looks for the max and min between 1 and n-2 and swaps them with 1 and n-2
and it keeps going until the table is organized
problem is when i print the expected organized table after compling all I find is random numbers

Comment: The code is unreadable. Please format it with consistent indentation and spacing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

- you're passing the address for the *permut* function so there's a chance of passing the same address twice so the value of that case becomes equal to 0
- and there's a chance where the smallest number is in the last case so the case containing the biggest number is switched with it then the biggest number is sent to the first case.
  So here's a revised version of your code with other minor fixes:

  ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   void permut(int *x, int *y)
   {
       *x=*x+*y;
       *y=*x-*y;
       *x=*x-*y;
   }
   void minimaxi(int t[],int bs,int bi,int *ma,int *mi)
   {
       int j;
       *ma=bi;
       *mi=bi;

       for(j=bi;j<=bs;j++)
           {

               if (t[j]<=t[*mi])
                   *mi=j;
           }
       if (*mi!=bi) permut(&(t[*mi]),&(t[bi]));
       for(j=bi;j<=bs;j++)
       {
           if (t[j]>t[*ma])
               *ma=j;
       }

       if (*ma!=bs) permut(&(t[*ma]),&(t[bs]));

   }

  void triminmax(int t[], int n)
  {
       int bi, bs, mx, mn;
       bs=n-1;
       bi=0;
       do 
       {
           minimaxi(t,bs,bi,&mx,&mn);
           bs=bs-1;
           bi++;
       }
       while(bs>=bi);
   }



   int main()
   {
       int *t, bs, bi, n, i,z;
       t=malloc(100*sizeof(int));
       printf("give the table length \n");
       scanf("%d", &n);
       z=n;
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
           printf("enter T[%d]\n", i);
           scanf("%d", t+i);
       }
       triminmax(t,n);
       for(i=0;i<z;i++)
       {
               printf("%d\n", t[i]);
       }

       return 0;
   }
  ```